# How to move GitHub repository from organization to my profile back?

Tags: github

I accidentally moved my repository to an organization, which is extremely inconvenient for my small team. I was looking at different forums, sites, but i couldn't find any answer.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/transferring-a-repository#

Comment: It's the same process, but it has to be done by someone within the organization that has the authority to transfer the repository.

Comment: Create a new empty repository in the org, and then add a new remote in your local git and push to that remote. You can also fork the repo to the org.

Answer (score 1):

1. Log in to your personal account with administrator or owner privileges in your organization.
2. Repository Setting > General > Click the red ‘transfer’ button at the bottom
3. Click `Select one of my organizations` and select your user name.